# Access variable in Google Maps Events addlistener

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

```
for(var i in coordenadas){
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker[i], 'click', toggleBounce);
}
```

togglebonce function:

```
function toggleBounce() {
      if (this.getAnimation() != null) {
        this.setAnimation(null);
        var i = "I WANT TO ACCESS OF VARIABLE i"
      } 
      else {
        this.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE);
      }
    }
```

In function toggleBounce() how I can access of variable i ? This variable is passed in ...addListener(marker[i]...

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to add it as a property of the marker when you create it (just be careful naming it so it doesn't conflict with an existing property of a `google.maps.Marker`).

```
// or here (since you didn't provide your code that creates the markers)
for(var i in coordenadas){
  marker[i]._index = i;
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker[i], 'click', toggleBounce);
}

function toggleBounce() {
  if (this.getAnimation() != null) {
    this.setAnimation(null);
    var i = this._index;
  } 
  else {
    this.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE);
  }
}
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/L6n54xds/19/)